# Validate if a binary search tree is full or not

Tags: binary-search-tree

How to validate if a binary search tree ( which is represented as a sorted array) is full or not? This needs to be done in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is balanced, just check to see if you have 2^(n-1)+1 elements